# Copying Folder of Images from local machine to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, mobile, firebase-storage

I have around 400 images, spread across in three local folders (it can be in a server or desktop), which I need to copy to firebase storage on a need basis. Once the work is completed, these images will be removed from the firebase storage. Please can you tell me how to copy the messages?

Thanks in advance for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Storage for Firebase and Google Cloud Storage are the same infrastructure, so you can use the [`gsutil cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) command to copy files:

```
gsutil cp some-folder/* gs://your-bucket-name/some-folder
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help. is this possible to use this command in windows machine?

Comment: Yes. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install

Comment: Brilliant help. Thanks